# Sliding list of DIVs with Prev & Next button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have next and previous buttons on a group of divs

```
<div><img src="img/car.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="img/boat.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="img/truck.jpg" /></div>
```

I have about 20 div's all floating left. Is there away to slide them back and forward with next and previous buttons?

Comment: Probably. What have you tried? Anything in particular you have problems with?

Comment: Hard to help if you don't show what you've tried

Comment: It depends on how big each `img` is, as if they are all different sizes the solution won't be so simple.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a similar question in the past https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747305/297641

So I edited that code a little to work with what you have,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/QScXU/20/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="prev">Previous</div>
<div class="nav-wrapper clearfix">
    <div>Car</div>
    <div>Boat</div>
    <div>Truck</div>
    <div>Van</div>
    <div>Bi-Cycle</div>
    <div>Omni</div>
    <div>Race Car</div>
</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var stPt = 0, elToShow = 5; //showing 5 elements

var $nav_wrapper = $('.nav-wrapper');
var $list = $nav_wrapper.find('div'); //get the list of div's
var $copy_list = [];
var copy_lgt = $list.length - elToShow;

//call to set thumbnails based on what is set
initNav();
function initNav() {
   var tmp;
   for (var i = elToShow; i < $list.length; i++) {
      tmp = $list.eq(i);
      $copy_list.push(tmp.clone());
      tmp.remove();
   }
}

$('.next').click (function () {
    $list = $nav_wrapper.find('div'); //get the list of div's

    //move the 1st element clone to the last position in copy_list
    $copy_list.splice(copy_lgt, 0, $list.eq(0).clone() ); //array.splice(index,howmany,element1,.....,elementX)

    //kill the 1st element in the div
    $list.eq(0).remove();

    //add to the last
    $nav_wrapper.append($copy_list.shift());
});

$('.prev').click (function () {
    $list = $nav_wrapper.find('div'); //get the list of li's

    //move the 1st element clone to the last position in copy_li
    $copy_list.splice(0, 0, $list.eq(elToShow-1).clone()); //array.splice(index,howmany,element1,.....,elementX)

    //kill the 1st element in the UL
    $list.eq(elToShow-1).remove();

    //add to the last
    $nav_wrapper.prepend($copy_list.pop());

});
```

Comment: So basically the idea here is for next to make the `lastchild` the `firstchild` and for previous to do the opposite. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks, very close i think. Here is what i have done. http://scott-p.dmlive.co.nz/formatives/pf-wp/ I would like to add next and previous buttons.